# How to find if an instruction post-dominates another in LLVM?

Tags: compilation, llvm, llvm-c++-api

Using the `llvm::DominatorTree` class, you can find out if an instruction dominates another. The necessary functions to do so are available: see

http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1DominatorTree.html

```
DT = DominatorTree(Func);
...
...
DT.dominates(I1,I2);
```

However, the same functions are not available for the `llvm::PostDominatorTree` struct. In fact, the latter's doxygen page is almost empty:

http://llvm.org/doxygen/structllvm_1_1PostDominatorTree.html

Is there a way to check postdominance as easily as dominance in LLVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of `PostDominatorTree`'s methods are inherited from `DominatorTreeBase`, including `dominates`. So this works the same as with `llvm::DominatorTree`

You find the doxygen documentation under "Public Member Functions inherited from `llvm::DominatorTreeBase< NodeT, IsPostDom >`".

Comment: Managed to make it work using the inherited functions. Unlike the `llvm::DominatorTree`, which has some helpful functions that make it easier to use it, the `PostDominatorTree` does not, so you need to do some extra stuff to do the same thing.